# How to connect to Ignite cluster from Local machine in Java Spring boot?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

```
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder=new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("<IPAddress>:47500..47509"));
        tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
```

Trying to connect to server node from client node using TCP IP Finder, but not able to connect.
My client node is in the local machine whereas the ServerNode is in a remote server.

Is it possible to connect to a remotely hosted Gridgain/Ignite server using Java Springboot from another machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Make sure that you use the correct address and port in the `IpFinder` configuration, as well as that the Discovery port on the remote host is reachable from the local machine. It could be that the port on the remote machine is closed or the firewall blocks the connection.

You can use `netcat` or a similar utility to check the connectivity. Here is a command example that should be executed on the local host:

```
nc -z <REMOTE_HOST_IP_ADDRESS> 47500
```

Also, you can find additional details regarding Ignite usage with Spring Boot applications in [this](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/tutorials/spring/spring-ignite-tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: I went through that tutorial, only thing is I am confused with the configuration. Could you please help me if you have any link/blog/tutorial link?

Comment: My motto is just to run my Spring Boot/Data application as a client node and use the Spring data features. Only the configuration is very much confusing for me, I am new to this. Kindly help if possible.